# Sentence suggestion for report an issue

Tags: coordination, repetition, coordination-of-unlikes

I see an alignment issue in one of the Stack Exchange site, I want to report the same in the Meta Stack Exchange. When compose the content for the issue in the end, I'm writing the content below:

> Is it for any purpose or is it a bug?

The repeating of **is it** is fine, or can I use any better sentence?

Comment: The repeating of **is it** is fine. Thank you for asking.

Comment: You can write it as *for purpose or bug, is it for any?*

Comment: @Ustanak: You certainly can't write anything like that if you want to sound anything like a native speaker.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, I phrased it like that since I've seen similar expressions in movies, for example.

Comment: @Ustanak: Perhaps you're talking about machine-translated subtitles. No native speaker would *ever* use anything remotely like the text you wrote.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Weird, perhaps it doesn't stand for BrE speakers, but if it's neither used both AmE or BrE, I won't use it again.

Comment: @Ustanak: You may well encounter some very unidiomatic (but easily understood) usages in areas where English is used as a *lingua franca*, but where native Anglophones are relatively uncommon. And it's just about *possible* some such usages may eventually come to be common in the local region (this often happens in India, I believe), but they will usually die off as more people become more competent in English, since they'll be increasingly associated with lack of fluency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it for any purpose **or is it** a bug?

Since the items joined *purpose* (the reason you wrote the code) and *bug* (a result of the actual coding) are not really related, repeating *is it* is fine. If you wrote:

> Is it a feature **or** a bug?

some code would likely result in a *feature* (the intended result) or a *bug* (some mistake). Being related opposites, writing it using only *or* is fine.